# Why deleting elements from a list in ruby does not work inside a for loop?

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for l in some_list
  some_list.delete_at(some_list.index(l))
end

puts some_list.inspect
```

It turns out, that at the end of the execution `some_list` is equal to `["b"]`.  Shouldn't it delete everything?

Comment: This shows the quirks of inplace operations (iterating over variables being modified may be the epitome of it).

Comment: If all you want to do is empty the list `some_list.clear` works well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first loop, l is at index 0, and 'a' gets deleted.

Then it loops again, and l is at index 1, which is now 'c' ('a' was deleted, remember?).  It deletes 'c' and is done :)

Comment: does this same explanation hold true for Array.each do?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to delete elements from a list in Ruby which are easier and safer than iterating through that list.

For example,

```
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]

# delete named elements
colors.delete("red")
=> ["green", "blue"]

# find difference in list and assign back to list
colors = colors - colors
=> []
```

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely have to delete while iterating, iterate in reverse so you're changing the array behind your iteration instead of ahead of it. But like the others said, in this case you probably shouldn't be looping in the first place.